# Adding Columns Sql Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server

I am having a problem with my SSRS. I have a task where on a table report one of the columns asks if something was done correctly. Y= yes and N=no. I need to automatically add up the Y's in the column. How do i do this? I need to post this above this column

Answer (score 1):

I've worked around things like this before by adding a calculated field to the dataset within SSRS with something like `IIF(Column.Value = "Y", 1, 0)` and then doing a `SUM()` of *that* field.  Alternatively there's probably a similar way to do a SUM or COUNT of the actual Ys within the table.